# Pandas Group By, defining output with indexes in rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have some data where the returns are grouped by month and year, but in the output the idea is to have years in rows and months in the columns (like this image that I found in Quantopian).

[image]

Currently what I do does this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=5000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5000,2) , columns=['ret', 'trend'], index = dates)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['ret'] = df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month], as_index=True)['ret'].sum()
print df2

               ret
2013 1   -0.888623
     2   -1.920381
     3   -2.253708
     4   -8.316681
     5   -2.426211
     6   -5.889560
     7   -4.072581
     8    0.669934
     9  -11.944923
     10  -1.429509
     11  -6.705022
     12   4.413347
2014 1   -2.819433
     2   -9.309527
     3    4.164549
     4    4.316265
     5   -6.489879
     6    0.599227
     7   -8.679500
     8   -7.031178
     9   -3.849903
     10   0.036255
     11   7.148089
     12   2.167552
2015 1   13.957739
     2   -4.248225
     3   -0.224388
     4    0.909705
     5   -6.561675
     6    0.207894
...            ...
2024 4    5.368534
     5   -5.405187
     6   -3.548288
     7   -1.253442
     8    3.510136
     9    0.964269
     10   4.044782
     11  -0.802436
     12  -2.461015
2025 1   -1.381566
     2   -3.026784
     3    1.402344
     4   -6.962486
     5    1.810279
     6   -2.330699
     7    2.624671
     8   -2.810254
     9   -5.865352
     10  20.853629
     11  -1.642405
     12   3.810005
2026 1   -6.433632
     2    0.345212
     3   -5.052783
     4    2.568629
     5   -0.031563
     6   -4.391030
     7   -6.286675
     8    2.329209
     9   -3.506839

[165 rows x 1 columns]
```

How can I do it for months to be the columns of this output?

Comment: IIUC do you want `df2.unstack(level=1)`?

Comment: @EdChum, that works perfect. 
Want to put it as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and pass `level=1` to unstack a specific level:

```
In [124]:
df2.unstack(level=1)

Out[124]:
           ret                                                         \
            1          2          3          4          5          6    
2013 -9.868992  -4.346157   3.866546  -8.626669   5.139571   6.279008   
2014 -1.535937  -7.150076  12.477616   3.913517  -3.305470  -2.865723   
2015  4.895234  -6.265481  -6.898884   0.097624  12.565113   2.195401   
2016 -4.526340  -2.936200  -5.912908   2.729341   0.815636  -4.912806   
2017 -1.546016   2.473249  -4.205015   4.102542  -4.458827   1.924468   
2018  6.475616   0.027515   2.638676  -6.600986  -2.903825  14.835129   
2019 -6.147727  -1.927974   2.574085 -11.910082  -1.879927   6.275029   
2020  1.888112   4.597125   3.380548  -3.843723   2.419507  -1.427722   
2021  1.004944   0.180754  -8.159088   9.789561  -1.085590   6.248256   
2022 -9.635066  -0.772752   1.445861  -5.435704  -0.863745  -2.939604   
2023 -1.161640   0.488229  -1.607350   0.228962   4.987129   7.192585   
2024 -1.183226  10.776812  -5.597332   3.118547  -0.655470  -0.738184   
2025  3.962616 -11.581283  -1.021046  -0.440242   1.403144  -7.224395   
2026 -1.977520   6.571101   0.003448   0.191040  -7.202345  -8.193564   


            7          8         9          10        11         12  
2013  2.959460  10.185449 -8.537985   4.659689  5.088191 -10.974003  
2014 -0.327318   0.456162  1.528933  17.446656 -7.539484 -13.894860  
2015 -3.673257  -5.406524  5.557376   2.645820  1.034233  -6.025324  
2016 -3.028106   0.193528 -1.870737  -7.610312  4.926571  -0.229560  
2017 -1.311885   3.934379 -3.117008   1.500675 -6.710537  -7.828733  
2018  5.751018  -2.329534  9.277459  -6.410702 -2.633642  -2.590974  
2019 -9.765319 -13.551314 -4.538661   2.563119 -2.949883  -3.896485  
2020  2.356527   4.775241 -1.428101  -5.261007  9.322340  -1.350198  
2021  0.509185  -4.233567  4.262016  -7.600269  6.084152  -0.804232  
2022  2.236611  -0.506173 -2.528419   0.518371  8.969728   1.970115  
2023  5.951624  -2.948382  0.814657  -5.907658 -2.376326   8.222634  
2024 -1.422230   4.984618 -1.196657  -4.488551 -2.509809  -6.104347  
2025 -1.306259   0.326205 -0.748180  -0.627567  8.017221   8.684555  
2026 -4.524792   0.101453 -3.360516        NaN       NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer!